# Which term is used to refer both to sentences and expressions shorter than a sentence?

Tags: terminology

I believe, "expression" is a good term for a word or a meaningful part of a sentence, which is shorter than the sentence, but "expression" does not sound a good term to refer to a sentence. Is there a term which would be appropriate for all these cases?

Is it acceptable to use the term "object of language" to refer to anything used in a discourse?

Comment: "Expression" includes "sentence". On the other hand, I don't think there is a short word for "non-sentential expression".

Comment: Phrase? Clause? All sentences are phrases of some sort.

Comment: All sentences are clauses of some sort. All clauses are composed of phrases, and sometimes can be used as phrases in other clauses. But that's all language constituents. _String_ refers to a sequence of ... anything -- a string of words, letters, phonemes, morphemes, whatever, as long as they're in sequence. Mostly strings don't make sense, though parts of them might. _Expressions_ are structured, strings aren't (except for order); expressions have meaning, but strings don't. Probably the word you're looking for is _Constituent_, which includes sentences and everything else useful.